# Cant Connect Moto G Phone

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, phone, adb

I have a android app I want to put to my phone. I cant get my device connected even, MOTO G Android 6.

```
[Ubuntu 14.04][Android 6 Phone]
```

I have usb debugging allowed and MTP enabled.

I have my udev rules of motorola id 22b8. I added the id to adb_usb.uni file.

Still no sign of any connection. `sudo adb devices` returns a blank line. adb starting restarting killing nothing changes anything.

PLease help.

Comment: This might be something to do with using Android 6.  My 1st Generation Moto G using Android 5.1 shows all the folders when connected to my Ubuntu 16.04 PC using USB.  If you think about it, this is very insecure.  So I think Android 6 may be blocking the connection for security reasons, even when you use adb.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's  "sudo adb devices" not " sudo adb devies"

And Try this

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

Comment: Hi, thx, as I tried they are not changing anything.